# Control the distance between letter and dot above it

Tags: symbols, accents

For equations, dots are required above letters. So, usually I use `\dot{}`. It is OK with small letters but with Capital letters the dot is too close to the letter. Can I increase the distance between the letter and the dot please?

Many thanks in advance.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\dot{W}_\textrm{actual, comp}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried some standard (Times-like?) fonts but none produces the output you show. Apparently you are working very hard to force TeX to give a bad output.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Please post a minimum working example (i.e., a file containing as little as possible that we can run through LaTeX to reproduce the problem).

Comment: @karlh through LaTeX or through another TeX format.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\dot{W}_\textrm{actual, comp}$\end{document}`, run through `pdflatex`, results in https://i.stack.imgur.com/czDfd.png --- which is ok. This question shows clearly why, in LaTeX, a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is fundamental.

Comment: Please note that your input is only working by accident, correct LaTeX input should be `\dot{W}_{\textrm{actual, comp}}` (note the additional braces around the entire subscript).

Comment: @Skillmon , you're right, of course, I always forgot those braces (and I have been bitten sometimes...)

Comment: I think the term en vogue is not MWE (minimal working example) but is MRE (minimal reproducible example) or MCVE (minimal complete and verifiable example) - [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve).

Comment: As noted in the comments, your example should have `{ }` around the subscript, and does not produce the image you claim it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blind guess is that `\mathstrut` (or whatever `\vphantom` producing some height) might add a bit of vertical whitespace:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

$\dot{W}_{\textrm{actual, comp}}$

$\dot{W\mathstrut}\mskip-.5\thickmuskip_{\textrm{actual, comp}}$

$\dot{W\vphantom{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}}\mskip-.5\thickmuskip_{\textrm{actual, comp}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, with my MWE the input `\dot{W}_{\textrm{actual, comp}}` on the TeX-platform in use on my side<sup>1</sup> doesn't yield a vertical gap between `W` and the dot as small as in the image provided by you.

I did a blind guess because you did not provide a minimal example which one can examine/compile for reproducing/tracing that behavior of the TeX-platform in use on your side which should be changed.

---

<sup>1</sup> console-output says about the TeX-platform in use on my side:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev) [...]
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

Comment: Many thanks. It did add space between the letter and the dot above.
Regarding my question, I though it doesn't need a complete example but thank you again.

Comment: Can I know how to increase this distance please?

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam If all else fails you can put a rule (`\rule{0pt}{<desired height>}`) of some height into a `\vphantom`. But you need to take care whether in `\scriptscriptstyle`/`\scriptstyle`/`\textstyle`/`\displaystyle`.

Comment: About complete example: The crucial point is: For some reason you get output which none of the readers of the questions seems to get. Thus the reason for this might be interesting for the readers so the readers can track down/trace and thus judge whether advice they intend to give is appropriate with the scenario encountered by you. || As your question uses `\mathrm` I just guessed that you use some release of LaTeX 2e.